# How do I correct these errors with a NSString in a View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, integer

I am converting a Integer to a NSString, I have some code but I have 11 errors.

Here is the code I am using:

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController  {

    int score;
    NSString *stringscore;
    NSString stringscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"d",score];
}
```

How exactly can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left off the % in the format string, and you don't need the second NSString

```
stringscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
```

Although in this case you could have put the variable definition and assignment all on one line:

```
NSString* stringscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
```

**Stupidity update**

In my frenzy to post (and being half asleep) I didn't see that this was all being done in the @Interface.

If should be split between the interface and the implementation .. the following is an example of how it could be done:

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController  {

    int score;
    NSString *stringscore;
}
@end

@implementation GameViewController

-(void)SomeMethod
{
   score = 123;
   stringscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful however I still have some errors. Now I have removed `NSString *stringscore;` and added the %. Do you see why this is happening?

Comment: Did you read what error messages say? My guess is that you are missing an asterisk. You should have `NSString *stringscore = `, not `NSString stringscore = `.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can assign values to variables in @interface section like that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest solution should be:

```
NSString *stringscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
```

However, given that score is an int, you could also do:

```
NSString* stringscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",score];
```

However, you should only be doing the assignment in the .m file, and only after giving score a value.

Comment: I didn't know you need to state this in your .m file, this helped however I get the error 'Initializer element is not a compile-time constant' when I put the code I have in the .m file.